# Lync presence is shown in IE8 but not in IE9 sharepoint 2010 contact list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-office, lync-2010

I am new to sharepoint.  I have sharepoint server 2010 and lync 2010 installed on the windows server 2008 R2. When I add any item to the list which has member field, lync presence icon is shown in IE8 but not in IE9. I have microsoft office 2010 installed on the machine.

I tried the so many things but did not succeed. Site is intranet and also added to the trusted site and name.dll is present.

Comment: Have you tried the developer tools in IE9 to see what is going on

Comment: Yes I tried developer tool. In IE8 image tag for presence shown in developer is as <img width="12" height="12" id="imn{ddwrt:Counter()}" onload="IMNRC('someone@something.com')" alt="Available" src="http://servername:2000/_layouts/images/imnon.png" border="0" valign="middle" ShowOfflinePawn="1"/> and in IE9 it shows same as above except alt="No presence available" and image is blank.gif